# With respect to JAVA multithreading, Is this publisher subscriber program correct?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package com.mypublishersubscriber;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;

class Publisher implements Runnable {

    Channel object = null;
    Random random = new Random();

    public Publisher(Channel object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void run() {

        synchronized (object) {

            while (true) {
                if (object.queue.size() == object.capacity) {
                    try {
                        object.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                int ele  = random.nextInt();
                System.out.println("put: "+ ele);
                object.queue.add(ele);
                object.notify();
            }

        }

    }

}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    Channel object = null;

    public Consumer(Channel object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void run() {

        synchronized (object) {
            
            while(true) {
                
                if (object.queue.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        object.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {

                    int ele = object.queue.poll();
                    System.out.println("read: "+ele);
                    object.notify();

                }
                
            }

            

        }

    }

}
/**
 * publisher and subscriber will connect to this main class and<br>
 * will publish to this object's queue and consume from this
 * @author subhasish
 *
 */
public class Channel {

    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    public final int capacity = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Channel object = new Channel();

        Publisher publisher = new Publisher(object);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(object);

        Thread producer = new Thread(publisher);
        Thread subscriber = new Thread(consumer);

        producer.start();
        subscriber.start();

    }

}
```

- I have created a Channel class whose "object" is used by both publisher and subscriber
- publisher has a synchronized block in run method, in which an infinite loop checks if the "channel's " queue is full, if it is, then if calls wait on the "channel" object and releases the lock, else adds elements to it, and notify, which eventually releases the lock again
- Consumer also has a synchronized block in run method, with an infinite loop to check if the "channel's" queue is empty, if yes, calls wait on "channel" and releases the lock, else, adds element to the "channel's" queue and notifies.

DOUBT:

- Am I using the channel object correctly?
- Am I using the "channel's" queue correctly, considering its shared with two threads, do I need to use volatile, or something like that?

The program is working and I am getting the correct output.
I know that there are advanced way of doing this, but I want to understand the wait and notify in this way.

Comment: eating the interrupted exceptions means this isn't going to stop cleanly on shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the channel object correctly because you're accessing it within synchronized blocks only. With explicit synchronization, you don't need to use volatile as synchronization operations include the necessary memory barrier.

However, your while loop is inside the synchronized block, so once one thread starts running, the other will wait until the running thread calls wait, that is until the queue is full or empty. You might consider moving the synchronized block into the while loop.